# screwed up my Video sequence editor view

Tags: interface, video-sequence-editor

What I want it to look like:
[image: It Should Look Like this But now Its Not]

How the VSE is now:
[image: But now It Looks Like This]

So Right now It Looks like the second image but I need it to be Image 1.
I'm Struggling to revert it back to normal.

Comment: Open your file in Blenders file browser and uncheck Load UI.

Answer (score 1):

1. Press (click) <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> over the corner and drag over property windows an arrow will appear.

[image]

2. Press (click) <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> over the menu button and click over dope sheet.

[image]

3. Press (click) <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> over the menu button and click over action editor.

[image]

4. Done.

Comment: OP wanted it the other way round...

Comment: LOL yeah i just notice. but is the same process, drag to open new window and select what need to see.